# "The name does not exist in the current context", C#

Tags: c#

It says my return value does not exists in the current context (accessHelper), and i can't figure out what the problem is?

Bonus question, can someone tell me what the "new" keyword does? All tutorials i've seen, it's there, but no explanation to what it does.

```
public AccessHelper GetAccessHelper(int id)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = QL01; Initial Catalog = SCAM; Integrated Security = True"))
    {
        var accessHelper = sqlCon.Query<AccessHelper>("getAccessHelper", new { id }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
    return accessHelper;   
}
```

Comment: Put your return statement inside the using.  Otherwise `accessHelper` does not exist _outside_ the using statement

Comment: `new` in that use is creating an [anonymous object](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-anonymous-type)

Comment: You could just make it one line inside of your `using` statement: `return sqlCon.Query<AccessHelper>("getAccessHelper", new { id }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

Comment: Do you understand the concept of [variable scope](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx)? `accessHelper` isn't in scope outside of the using block.

Comment: Read up on scope as commented above. The `new` keyword creates a "new' object by calling its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is declared inside another scope, you can't access it from a upper scope.

The `new` keyword initializes a collection with the variable `id` inside, as for `new SqlConnection` it calls the constructor to create an `SqlConnection` object with the given arguments.

```
public AccessHelper GetAccessHelper(int id)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = QL01; Initial Catalog = SCAM; Integrated Security = True"))
    {
        var accessHelper = sqlCon.Query<AccessHelper>("getAccessHelper", new { id }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        return accessHelper;  
    }
}
```

Comment: The `accessHelper` variable is not needed here, you could just return the result of `Query()`

Comment: You might want to distinguish between `new { id }`, the short-hand collection initializer, and `new SqlConnection(..)`, the standard constructor call.

Comment: True, but that shows why the accessHelper variable raises an error.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer reagarding the new keyword, that makes sense, regarding the scope.. Guess i'm an idiot or tired :) 
However, i tried maccettura and Maxime B's solutions, and yes, the accessHelper is now accessable, however now i get the following error 
"cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable"
And then it asks if i am missing a cast? 
An explicit conversion exists?

Comment: The error is on the " return accessHelper"

Comment: I guess that `Query` method is returning `IEnumerable<AccessHelper>`, and you want the single result contained inside it? Try `return accessHelper.SingleOrDefault();` (OrDefault means return null if the collection is empty)